# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP max length

Tags: oracle, timestamp, oracle12c

I'd like to have a table `Tab1` with a field `Var1` that is concatenation of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and some other fields (`Var2` and `Var3`). The insert for this table would look like:

```
INSERT INTO Tab1
(...
Var1,
...)
select
...
Var2 || CURRENT_TIMESTAMP || Var3 as Var1
...
from Tab2
```

I need to know what might be maximum length of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in order to set correct length for `Var1` in `Tab1`. I guess this length may differ while length of time zone names are different ie.

> 19/05/07 16:03:24,782930 EUROPE/BELGRADE

is longer than

> 19/05/07 16:03:24,782930 ASIA/KUWAIT

Is it possible to define what is maximum length of string I get from `CURRENT_TIMESTMAP`? Btw, changing it to `LOCALTIMESTAMP` is not a solution in that case.

Comment: Just set it to something like 100 chars. Just because the limit is larger than you need doesnt mean while take more space. Is just a restriction limit, in the disk you only will save the same as the string length

Comment: Timezone with maximum length (32) in `v$timezone_names` is `America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia` if this helps :)

Comment: Why do you like to concatenate a TIMESTAMP value with other strings? Usually this is a bad idea.

Comment: The output format of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` depends on current user session `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT`. For example if you use `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSTZHTZM'` then the length is fixed 19 characters

Comment: It doesn't even make sense to ask what is the "maximum length" of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`; what you're asking is what is the maximum length of a particular string encoding of a time value, but this is entirely up to you to decide based on your choice of formatting and precision. Ultimately it doesn't seem like a very good idea; the builtin TIMESTAMP format is designed to unambiguously represent a time value, why not use it?